# Rails: How to run "rake" commands using Bash script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bash

I created **reset_db.sh** (with `chmod +x`) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "*** Deleting the database ***"
rake db:drop --trace
echo "*** Creating the database ***"
rake db:create --trace
echo "*** Migrating the database ***"
rake db:migrate --trace
echo "*** Seeding the database ***"
rake db:seed --trace
echo "*** Done! ***"
```

However, when I run:

```
bash reset_db.sh
```

I see:

```
*** Deleting the database ***
*** Creating the database ***
*** Migrating the database ***
*** Seeding the database ***
*** Done! ***
```

but the `rake` commands were not executed.

Any ideas why ?

**Bonus question:**

What should I do in order to be able to run `reset_db.sh` rather than `bash reset_db.sh` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to run the command you need to type:

```
./reset_db.sh
```

Regarding the rake command, are you in the folder where the rake should be launched?

Comment: I think Matteo's on to something: I can't duplicate this issue on my local project. Make sure the file is in the same location as the project's Rakefile.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was totally different from what I thought... After running `dos2unix` on `reset_db.sh`, it started to work :) Thanks anyway for your time!

Answer (score 5):

Add `set -x` at the top of your bash script for more verbose output.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

echo "*** Deleting the database ***"
rake db:drop --trace
echo "*** Creating the database ***"
rake db:create --trace
echo "*** Migrating the database ***"
rake db:migrate --trace
echo "*** Seeding the database ***"
rake db:seed --trace
echo "*** Done! ***"
```

Does that give you any further information?